# What are the real benefits of using a bang function (Repo.get!) when building a json api?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm building a json API using Elixir/Phoenix, and the framework generated my UserController with this method

```
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Repo.get!(User, id)
    render(conn, "show.json", user: user)
end
```

If I search for an existing user it's all good, if I search for a non existent user I get the following exception

> (Ecto.NoResultsError) expected at least one result but got none in query:

which, if I turn off debugging, it returns a 404. That might sound find for a web app, but if I'm building a json api I'd prefer to get a null result in json, which is what I get if I remove the exclamation mark on Repo.get

> {"data":null}

Is it still recommended to use the bang function? what are its benefits when building a json API?

cheers

Comment: It is only recommended to use a bang function if it is okay to fail. If you would prefer to get a `nil` value, you should not use a bang function.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, wanted to make sure though